Find groups of N people such that everyone meets, but with minimal overlap?
I am trying to find a way to generate a schedule for lunch meetings of size 4 persons. I have 28 people who will participate in one meeting every month for a year, meaning that 7 individual lunches should be scheduled every month.

Every person should have lunch with every other person. When they have lunch together they become "lunch buddies".
Every person attends one lunch per month.
Two people should not be in the same group (be lunch buddies) more than statistically necessary to achieve the other requirements.

I have tried starting with N choose K groups and then eliminating duplicates, but this is a brute force approach. It will be necessary to allow repeat lunch buddies, but I am having trouble finding any elegant solution which minimizes repeat buddies more than random chance.
This is one brute force approach I've taken: Start with NchooseK groups, but at each step we populate a dictionary where the key is the person and the value is a list of their lunch buddies. We then use the dictionary to inform decisions about the next groups we pick up from the NchooseK list:
import itertools

array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2'] 
schedule = []
monthsSchedule = []
dictionary = {}

def updateDictionary(group):
    #keep record of who has already met with who
    a = group[0]
    b = group[1]
    c = group[2]
    d = group[3]
    if a in dictionary:
        dictionary[a].extend([b, c, d])
    else:
        dictionary[a] = [b, c, d]
    if b in dictionary:
        dictionary[b].extend([a, c, d])
    else:
        dictionary[b] = [a, c, d]
    if c in dictionary:   
        dictionary[c].extend([a, b, d])
    else:
        dictionary[c] = [a, b, d]
    if d in dictionary:
        dictionary[d].extend([a, b, c])
    else:
        dictionary[d] = [a, b, c]


def isValidGroup(group):
    #a valid group is one where the people in the group have not already met together.
    if len(dictionary) == 0:
        return True
    a = group[0]
    b = group[1]
    c = group[2]
    d = group[3]
    if a in dictionary:
        if b in dictionary.get(a) or c in dictionary.get(a) or  d in dictionary.get(a):
            return False
    if b in dictionary:
        if a in dictionary.get(b) or c in dictionary.get(b) or  d in dictionary.get(b):
            return False
    if c in dictionary:
        if a in dictionary.get(c) or b in dictionary.get(c) or  d in dictionary.get(c):
            return False
    if d in dictionary:
        if a in dictionary.get(d) or b in dictionary.get(d) or  c in dictionary.get(d):
            return False
    return True

def fillMonthSchedule(nchoosek):
    skip = False #
    peopleScheduled = []
    schedule = []
    while len(schedule) < 7 and len(nchoosek) > 0:
        group = nchoosek.pop(0)

        for person in group:
            skip = False
            if person in peopleScheduled: #if the person has already been scheduled this month, we cannot schedule them again
                skip = True
                break
        if isValidGroup(group) and not skip:
            schedule.append(group)
            for person in group:
                peopleScheduled.append(person) #maintain local list of who has already been scheduled in this month
            updateDictionary(group)
    return schedule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nchoosek = []
     #start picking groups, maintain dictionary of who has seen who already
    for i in range(0, 12): #create one schedule for each month of the year
        for comb in itertools.combinations(array, 4):
            nchoosek.append(comb) #get the full set of n choose k of size 4
        monthsSchedule.append(fillMonthSchedule(nchoosek))
    print(monthsSchedule

This gives a result with only one valid month, as subsequent months do not schedule all participants:
[[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('e', 'f', 'g', 'h'), ('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'), ('m', 'n', 'o', 'p'), ('q', 'r', 's', 't'), ('u', 'v', 'w', 'x'), ('y', 'z', '1', '2')],

 [('a', 'e', 'i', 'm'), ('b', 'f', 'j', 'n'), ('c', 'g', 'k', 'o'), ('d', 'h', 'l', 'p')],

 [('a', 'f', 'k', 'p'), ('b', 'e', 'l', 'o'), ('c', 'h', 'i', 'n'), ('d', 'g', 'j', 'm')],

 [('a', 'g', 'l', 'n'), ('b', 'h', 'k', 'm'), ('c', 'e', 'j', 'p'), ('d', 'f', 'i', 'o')],

 [('a', 'h', 'j', 'o'), ('b', 'g', 'i', 'p'), ('c', 'f', 'l', 'm'), ('d', 'e', 'k', 'n')],

 [('a', 'q', 'u', 'y'), ('b', 'r', 'v', 'z'), ('c', 's', 'w', '1'), ('d', 't', 'x', '2')],

 [('a', 'r', 'w', '2'), ('b', 'q', 'x', '1'), ('c', 't', 'u', 'z'), ('d', 's', 'v', 'y')],

 [('a', 's', 'x', 'z'), ('b', 't', 'w', 'y'), ('c', 'q', 'v', '2'), ('d', 'r', 'u', '1')],

 [('a', 't', 'v', '1'), ('b', 's', 'u', '2'), ('c', 'r', 'x', 'y'), ('d', 'q', 'w', 'z')],

 [],

 [],

 []]


Possible duplicate of Arrange 14 people into groups of 4 such that every person meets once minimum.

Hey there! Can I ask why you un-accepted my answer? Let me know if there's anything you'd like me to change or clarify.

Have you considered using itertools.combinations? This code provides all the combinations of 4 elements taken from the input array
import itertools

array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2']

meetings = [mtg for mtg in itertools.combinations(array, 4)]
print(meetings)
# [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'h'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'i'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'j'), ... 
# and so on...

Since this is a 'people problem', you could conceivably randomly chose a permutation from this list as needed in order to avoid some of the unwanted 'overlapping'.
If we assume this list is the same length as the number of people involved, then you have 20,475 combinations of 4 to choose from (this is the result of len(mettings) if you're curious).
This means if you randomly choose 7 combos each month, it will take 2,925 months (just shy of 244 years!) to exhaust all possible combinations.
